# Reference for Dedekind's Example of a Non-monogenic Field

Tags: number-theory, math-history

An oft quoted fact is that Dedekind discovered that adjoining a root of $x^3-x^2-2x-8$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ yields a number field that is not monogenic. Does anyone know exactly where Dedekind writes this? In other words, does anyone have the citation for this?

Comment: I presume you mean that the integers of the field can not be generated over $\Bbb Z$ by a single element.

Comment: Yes, by monogenic we mean that the ring of integers admits a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the form $\{1,\theta,\theta^2,\dots, \theta^{n-1}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be found e.g. in his announcement of the second edition of Dirichlet's Lectures in Number Theory (Gött. gelehrte Anzeigen 1871, 1481--1494; see Dedekind Werke, vol III, p. 406). He published the details in *Über den Zusammenhang zwischen der Theorie der Ideale und der Theorie der höheren Kongruenzen*, Gött. Abhandlungen 1878, 1--23; Werke II, 202-223; see in particularp. 225.